# jQuery sortable - drop between non-sortable items

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Take this example: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items. How can I make the list able to drop between elements two and three (both non-sortable)?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up implementing draggable + droppable myself. This is not really an answer, but it is a way to achieve the same results.